# Como adicionar símbolo monetário de euro (€) em uma página .tex no LaTeX?

Tags: latex

Estou fazendo minha monografia de TCC no Overleaf e estou com dificuldades em inserir o símbolo de euro (€) em uma página .tex do template que minha faculdade oferece para desenvolver a monografia.

**Concluindo: Eu queria renomear 50 mil euros para € 50.000**

```
\chapter{REVISÃO BIBLIOGRÁFICA/TEÓRICA}
\label{chap:fundamentacaoTeorica}

...
que custa 50 mil euros teve como pontos fortes a cor...
...
```

Comment: Veja: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252998/how-can-i-compile-latex-in-utf8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o pacote [eurosym](http://www.theiling.de/eurosym.html).

#### Utilização

```
\usepackage{eurosym}
...
The book is 10 \euro.
The book is \euro 10.
The book is \EUR{10}.
\textbf{The book is \EUR{10}.}
\textit{The book is \EUR{10}.}
```

Se estiver utilizando o UTF-8, você pode declarar facilmente:

```
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\euro}
```

Ou se estiver utilização uma codificação diferente, como a latin9:

```
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\let € = \euro
...
Das Buch kostet 10 €.
```

Creio que o modo mais simples é declarar o pacote e utilizar a sua função, que já faz as adaptações para cada tipo de codificação:

```
\usepackage{eurosym}
...
\EUR{50.000}
```

Veja um exemplo no [Overleaf](https://pt.overleaf.com/read/cbmhvrvhkzng).

Comment: onde eu coloco o `\usepackage{eurosym}`na própria pagina .tex da revisão bibliográfica/teórica?

Comment: Isso, no início do arquivo `.tex`, onde ficam todas as declarações de pacotes. Veja um [exemplo](https://pt.overleaf.com/latex/templates/federal-university-of-technology-parana-ic-report/gkjvhwrtkvps), em que fica junto com os outros `\usepackage{pacote}`

Comment: Consegui, eu tive que inserir `\usepackage{eurosym}` no `pacote.tex` do meu template. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Na monografia brasileira, é aconselhável usar `€ 50.000` ou `50.000 €` para descrever o valor?

Comment: Não sei informar isso, você deve consultar a norma utilizada. Mas em notícias e outros, normalmente é utilizado o € valor.